# Node scripts run as root, aren't able to gain credentials access on Ubuntu in AWS, is this so?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

AWS EC2, OS: Ubuntu: 18+
Running a Node script to list/upload to S3 works, so long as I run it as user **ubuntu**
However, when using CodeDeploy I ended up running them as **root** (this may be a questionable practice) and this throws:

```
root@ip-172-31-58-175:~/nodetest# node s3.js
Error { InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
    at Request.extractError (/root/nodetest/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:837:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/root/nodetest/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/root/nodetest/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/root/nodetest/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/root/nodetest/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/root/nodetest/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /root/nodetest/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/root/nodetest/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/root/nodetest/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/root/nodetest/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
  message: 'The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.',
  code: 'InvalidAccessKeyId',
  region: null,
  time: 2020-08-24T14:27:47.253Z,
  requestId: '*********D762',
  extendedRequestId: ''*********/1SbU2uA6*******V8FwOOgcX+6qdVQ=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 38.407343636830134 }
```

```
root@ip-172-31-58-175:~/nodetest# aws sts get-caller-identity

An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
root@ip-172-31-58-175:~/nodetest# aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************ILFL]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************tBil]:
Default region name [us-west-2]:
Default output format [json]:
```

Answer (score 0):

The manner in which you're handling AWS credentials is on a per-user basis.  This information is stored in `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`.  Your ubuntu user must have these values setup already, perhaps with a `aws configure` command.

There are two ways of fixing this.  The first is to simply copy the files from what is likely `/home/ubuntu/.aws` to `/root/.aws` (you will likely have to create `/root/.aws`).  This makes the credentials the same for both users.  However, while this will work if you spin up a new instance you'll have to go through this again.

A better way is to associate an IAM profile to the entire EC2 instance.  This means that any user on the machine can access credentials and that you can change them on a per machine basis if you'd like.  The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) goes into more details but the basic idea is to create an IAM role for your instance or instances.  When you create the EC2 in the console you can associate a role then:

[image]

or, after creation, you can associate it:

[image]

There are also ways of associating the role with the AWS cli if you use that.  Either way your entire machine now has the ability to run commands with the permissions you've given to the role.  If you want to change those permissions you can after the association.

You didn't show your code but in general it should become a bit simpler.  If you're using the default security managers they will pick up this change without any code changes.  If you're having an issue, open a new question to get the security managers setup.